# One-liner POSIX command to lowercase string in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, posix

## Problem

I have this comand:

```bash
sed $((SS - default_scripts))!d customScripts.txt
```

and it gives me `Foo Bar`.

**I want to convert this to lowercase**.

## Attempt

When I tried using the `| awk '{print tolower($0)}'` command on it it returned nothing:

```bash
$($(sed $((SS - default_scripts))!d customScripts.txt) | awk '{print tolower($0)}')
```

## Final

Please enlighten me on my typo, or recommend me another POSIX way of converting a whole string to lowercase in a compact manner. Thank you!

Comment: If `tolower` would not be valid, awk would print an error message, wouldn't it?

Comment: good point ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe to awk should be inside the same command substitution as `sed`, so that it processes the output of `sed`.

```
$(sed $((SS - default_scripts))!d customScripts.txt | awk '{print tolower($0)}')
```

You don't need another command substitution around both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your typo was wrapping everything in `$(...)` and so first trying to execute the output of just the `sed` part and then trying to execute the output of the `sed ... | awk ...` pipeline.

You don't need sed commands nor shell arithmetic operations when you're using awk. If I understand what you're trying to do with this:

```
$(sed $((SS - default_scripts))!d customScripts.txt) | awk '{print tolower($0)}'
```

correctly then it'd be just this awk command:

```
awk -v s="$SS" -v d="$default_scripts" 'BEGIN{n=s-d} NR==n{print tolower($0); exit}' customScripts.txt
```